# Does it make sense to compare two different DVs on a within-subjects t-test or MANOVA (or ANOVA?)?

Tags: anova, t-test, independence, manova, medicine

Let's say I have 3 different drug doses: A, B and C and I have two DVs: blood pressure and pulse. I am interested in finding out if the three doses *differentially* impact the two DVs (i.e. if at dose A blood pressure is more different than pulse vs at dose B or dose C) - basically if there is an interaction between the DVs. I'm wondering what test to use to measure if this difference is statistically significant.

If I just had two different treatments, I would just use a repeated-measures ANOVA I think, but what is tripping me up is that these are not two different IVs on the same group but one IV and two different DVs. Is what I am trying to do equivalent to just having two IVs?

Edit: let's just say I want to treat the doses as categorical for now. But if there is a regression-based solution I could try that too.